# Excel 2013 slow when Cell Editing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013 (on windows 7), when I select a cell & type something, most of the time it makes the computer very slow for few seconds, and takes time to display entered text in the cell.

- Tried disabling all Com Add-ins, but no avail.
- Tried opening the Excel in safe mode using `Excel /safe` command then it works fine.

What could be the reason causing this issue?

Comment: Is this macro enabled or just normal?

Comment: @DaveRook It happens even on New Spreadsheet..

Comment: And can I assume the PC is at (at least) minimum required spec? And (Sorry to ask) can you confirm you're working locally (ie, not opening a file over a network)

Comment: Yes I think so, It has core 2 Duo 2.8 processor and 2 GB RAM. Once I felt the slowness happened on Excel start but I didn't experience it at any time other than on cell editing...

Comment: @DaveRook This happens even before the file saved on the hard disk...

Comment: Do you ever watch videos/play games? If so, do you get any slow down then? Please run a SMART tool just in case (I know Excel does some automatic saving etc). Or, try it with just 1 RAM chip.

Comment: @DaveRook No I do not experience it in any other application, I'll try  with 1 RAM chip...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar experience on low spec PC (P4@3Ghz).

Try disable animations:

1. `WIN+R`
2. Type `regedit`and hit `Enter`
3. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common`
4. Look for `Graphics` folder (if is missing, create it)
5. Open this folder (graphics) and create new `DWORD(32bit)` named
   `DisableAnimations` and set value to 1

OR copy

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics]
"DisableAnimations"=dword:00000001
```

to Notepad a save as *.reg and then apply by doubleclick on this *.reg file

AND (optionally)

In Excel go to Preferences-advanced and `disable HW acceleration`

Comment: Here is tutorial with images (translate by google) [https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblogistak.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F05%2F10%2Fpomaly-office-2013-je-treba-vypnout-animace%2F&edit-text=](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblogistak.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F05%2F10%2Fpomaly-office-2013-je-treba-vypnout-animace%2F&edit-text=)

Comment: Wow this registry fix seems to have done the trick on Excel 2016, nothing else worked. I'll give feedback after a week :)

Comment: Yes. it worked.

Comment: It's not working... (My windows is 7 with 2GB of RAM) i have added a new and simple answer that worked for me: https://superuser.com/questions/719435/excel-2013-slow-when-cell-editing/1679670#1679670

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some macro running at background. Even there is no com addin show, excel may also load the addin at background.
Also check whether you have some auto added or hided sheet?

Comment: He already said this happens on a new document in the comments above new documents are not macro enabled.

Answer (score 0):

### Some common issues that can really slow down an excel-spread sheet are:

- **Size (columns by rows)** ( if you accidentally navigate to say cell: **F1048576** and add a value or format to the cell, excel will think  your spreadsheet has millions of cells )
- **Formatting, conditional formatting** (When using conditional formatting, if you delete lines, or copy and paste values between unrelated columns it also copies the conditional formatting making the conditional-rule a little more complicated.
- **macros that are running. **( hint: **esc** *OR* **Ctrl + Break** to terminate macro )
- **Hidden rows** If you have ALL rows hidden after 8000 ( for example ) and you select a whole column, this can often lag the spread-sheet.

Does this problem persist on newly created spread-sheets? Have you tried to remove excel from your computer and re-add it? Perhaps it is time to reformat your computer -- or to buy a newer computer that meets the minimum requirements.

### Online/ Web-App Alternative:

- Try https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx
- google-drive "google sheets," (I think it is the better option for spreadsheets in-terms of speed & functionality.)
- Or Zoho.com there is a spread-sheet webapp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Totally ruined my mood each time.

1. Press Windows-Key+U for Ease of Access Center.
2. Go to "Use computer without a display"
3. check the box "Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)"

I believe that's what I used. But here are some more ideas on this forum: [Link to forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9c40dbbe-78d1-40cc-baa8-04067a601880/excel-2013-very-slow-response?forum=excel).

Fix 2:

Try disabling Hardware Acceleration in Display Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Excel recalculates everything each time time you enter data in a field. If your sheet has too many or too complex calculations, it will take a lot of time everytime.

Check how long a recalculation of your sheet takes:
Hit F9 and see if there is a noticable time until it's done (in the status line, percentages are counting to 100 or such).

If there *is* such a delay, you can either

- switch off instant calculation (on the Formula tab, right side under Calculations). This will solve your issue, but you will need to remember to hit F9 every time you want the calculations done; otherwise, you will see stale data / outdated results
- find out what exactly takes so long, and rewrite the formulas to be faster, or remove some
- tell Excel to use all available cores (under Options/Advanced)
- get a faster computer...

Answer (score 0):

Easily resolve the problem with this short answer:

File > Options > Advanced > Under (Display) Section > Turn On (Disable hardware graphics acceleration)

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2013-excel-is-very-slow-when-entering-data-and/73f0d973-4807-40fd-8bd2-fc1c6cc80374)